# Understanding Bereshit 1:30

Tags: animals, parashat-bereishit, eating, fruits, vegetables

Bereshit 1:30 says

> וּֽלְכָל־חַיַּ֣ת הָ֠אָרֶץ וּלְכָל־ע֨וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֜יִם וּלְכֹ֣ל ׀ רוֹמֵ֣שׂ עַל־הָאָ֗רֶץ אֲשֶׁר־בּוֹ֙ נֶ֣פֶשׁ חַיָּ֔ה אֶת־כָּל־יֶ֥רֶק עֵ֖שֶׂב לְאָכְלָ֑ה וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן׃
>
> And to all the animals on land, to all the birds of the sky, and to everything that creeps on earth, in which there is the breath of life, [I give] all the green plants for food.” And it was so.

1. my understanding is that the term עֵ֖שֶׂב implies vegetation which grows from the ground, as opposed to fruit from a tree. Why were all the animals prohibited from eating fruit?
2. throughout the rest of chapter 1 when the phrase וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן is used it is in conjunction with creation turning out the way God said it should. Here the phrase seems out of place, what is וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן in reference to?

Answer (score 5):

Mefarshim [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/1.30#e0n7):

Q1)

Shadal there (it's a really long piece, worth reading in its entirety) opposes your understanding, as he notes the opinion that animals were prohibited from eating fruit, and disagrees, noting:

> ‫ ואין להוציא מזה כדעת Grotius שנאסר פרי העץ לב״ח ‬

Ralbag also says clearly that fruit was included in "Yerek Esev", as do Rav Saadyah Gaon and Ibn Ezra to 1:29.  (Netziv possibly gives justification for such an opinion by noting Shemos 14:15.)

Q2)

Radak and Rav Avraham ben Harambam explain it as "creation turning out the way God said it should".  God said that they should eat from the Yerek Esev, and they did.